# No suggestion for misspelled added words

Tags: dictionary, autocorrect, spelling

I've added a word to the Mac dictionary.  When I spell it correctly, I have no problem. If I misspell it, I don't get suggestion that includes my correct spelling. This happens even when my misspelling is very close to correct. Can I get a correction for a word I added, but later in use, misspell?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own corrections in **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Text**. These corrections can be used to correct misspellings for any word, regardless of whether you've added the word to the dictionary yourself. Add your misspelling to the 'Replace' and the correct spelling to 'With', and repeat for multiple misspellings.